# Limit the integer range in textbox

Tags: c#, javascript

I put Text-box in grid-view and Bind that text-box value to data-table value. When there is 0 integer then text-box is not shown, and when value greater than 0 that specific value is shown in text box.

**ASP CODE:**

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtQuantity" Text='<%# Bind("InStock_Quantity") %>' Style="text-align: right;" onfocus="this.select()"runat="server" OnTextChanged="OnTextChange" Visible='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("InStock_Quantity")) %>'  AutoPostBack="true" ></asp:TextBox>

    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfv_txtQuantity" ControlToValidate="txtQuantity"
 ErrorMessage="enter quantity in order grid " InitialValue='<%# Bind("InStock_Quantity") %>' Text="*" ValidationGroup="form" runat="server"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
</ItemTemplate>
```

[image]

I want if user write more then that value show in text-box the message will display **"Quantity enter is greater than available quantity!"** and value must be restricted to value <= that value like "90".

Javascript is good then how could I do???

Comment: Since you are already on WebForms, why not use the [RangeValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f70d09xt(v=vs.85).aspx)? It will generate the javascript for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In ASP.NET you can use the Range Validator and set a min and max. For example:

```
<asp:RangeValidator ID="RangeValidator1" runat="server" Type="Integer" ControlToValidate="txtQuantity" MaximumValue="90" MinimumValue="1"
 ValidationGroup="form" ForeColor="Red" ErrorMessage="Must be equal or less than 90" />
```

Comment: Thank U, your guidance help me a lot !

Answer (score 0):

try this, it maybe helpful to you

```
<asp:CompareValidator runat="server" Operator="DataTypeCheck" Type="Integer" 
ControlToValidate="ValueTextBox" ErrorMessage="Value must be a whole number" />

<asp:RangeValidator runat="server" Type="Integer" 
MinimumValue="0" MaximumValue="400" ControlToValidate="ValueTextBox" 
ErrorMessage="Value must be a whole number between 0 and 400" />
```